# i need to save excel file based on the column value

Tags: excel, vba

[excel sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keOIE.png)

I have a vba code i need to save the file based on first 5 digits in f column in the given format

```txt
01_03_1396A_yyyymmdd
01_03_0001A_yyyymmdd
01_03_0003A_yyyymmdd
```

the above mentioned 1396A,0001A,0003A(is 5 digits in F column)

the problem is i dont know how to save based on first five digits on f column can anyone correct the below code

VBA CODE

```vb
Sub SplitSheetIntoMultipleWorkbooksBasedOnColumn()
    Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim nLastRow    As Integer, nRow As Integer, nNextRow As Integer
    Dim strColumnValue As String
    Dim objDictionary As Object
    Dim varColumnValues As Variant
    Dim varColumnValue As Variant
    Dim objExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objSheet    As Excel.Worksheet
    Set objWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    nLastRow = objWorksheet.Range("A" & objWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For nRow = 2 To nLastRow
        strColumnValue = Left(objWorksheet.Range("F" & nRow).Value, 5)
        If objDictionary.Exists(strColumnValue) = FALSE Then
            objDictionary.Add strColumnValue, 1
        End If
    Next
    
    varColumnValues = objDictionary.Keys
    For i = LBound(varColumnValues) To UBound(varColumnValues)
        varColumnValue = varColumnValues(i)
        Set objExcelWorkbook = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Add
        Set objSheet = objExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        objSheet.Name = objWorksheet.Name
        objWorksheet.Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy
        objSheet.Activate
        objSheet.Range("A1").Select
        objSheet.Paste
        objExcelWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\User\Desktop\New folder\" & "01_03_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx"
        
        For nRow = 2 To nLastRow
            If Left(CStr(objWorksheet.Range("F" & nRow).Value), 5) = CStr(varColumnValue) Then
                objWorksheet.Rows(nRow).EntireRow.Copy
                nNextRow = objSheet.Range("A" & objWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                objSheet.Range("A" & nNextRow).Select
                objSheet.Paste
                objSheet.Columns("A:H").AutoFit
                
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is nearly complete. Concatenate `varColumnValue` with other strings for the filename.

```
    objExcelWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\User\Desktop\New folder\" & _
        "01_03_" & varColumnValue & "_" & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx"
```

Comment: @ramya this may help in future  ...  https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html